# How to create a collapsible html/bootstrap checkbox table populated from mysql database using for loops?

Tags: php, css, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a checkbox table by populating the header and the first column from my sql database using multiple for loops. I want to break a for loop in between based on the Id in the database.

There are 4 tables in the database... Course, Goals, MainObjectives and SubObjectives. The header of the table is populated from the Course table. Now, The first column would have data from the rest of the tables. Row Goals should be collapsible when expanded it should show us MainObjectives and SubObjectives. Only the SubObjectives would have checkboxes.
Here's the database structure:

Course: courseId commonName

Goals: GoalId Goals

MainObjectives: MainObjId GoalId MainObjectives

SubObjectives:  SubObjId MainObjId SubObjectives

report.php

```
<form id="addReport" action ='./functions/report-functions.php' method="post">

<table id="table1" class="table table-hover">

    <thead> 
    <?php
    echo '<tr><th>Objectives</th>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($course); $i++) {
        echo '<th id = "rotate1" >'. $course[$i]->commonName . '</th>';            
    }
    echo '</tr>';   
    ?>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
               <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
    <?php
    for ($y = 0; $y < count($goals); $y++) {
        echo '<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable"><th class=row-header>'.$goals[$y]['Goals'].'</th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>';

   for ($z = 0; $z < count($mainobj); $z++) {
        echo '<tr><th class=row-header>'.$mainobj[$z]['MainObjectives'].'</th>
           <td></td>
        </tr>';

    for ($j = 0; $j< count($subobj); $j++) {
        echo '<tr><td class=row-header>'.$subobj[$j]['SubObjectives'].'</td>';
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($course); $x++) {

        echo "<td><input name='check[]' type=checkbox value=c".$course[$x]->courseId."-o".$subobj[$j]->SubObjId." id=checked></td>";

        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    }
   }
    ?>    
    <tr>
        </tbody>       
</table>
<input type="submit" name= "submit" value= "Submit"/>
```

report-functions.php

```
<?php

class Report {
    public static function getGoals() {
        $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Goals');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static function getMainObjectives() {
        $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM MainObjectives');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static function getSubObjectives() {
        $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM SubObjectives');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static function getCourse() {
        $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Course');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

With the above code, The for-loop for the subobjectives executes main-objectives number of times. I want to break it after the first mainobjective and so on.. 
I also want help in making the Goals rows collapsible.

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: I think you have an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: You can use `foreach` loop, is there a reason why you don't use it?

Comment: How would that help? Mainly the MainObjectives and SubObjectives should be fetched based on Ids and the for loop should have a break accordingly.  I am not sure on how to do it.

Comment: You have some redundant, difficult to read code. Proper formatting and naming would help.

Comment: Can you help me with the part you don't understand. I'll edit and elaborate it.

Comment: I do not know what your actual question is. There is a lot of content in this question and yet I do not know what you are struggling with.

Comment: I just want to categorize data from different table of the database. Goals, Main Objectives and SubObjectives. I'm doing it using for loops but I'm not sure how to break a for loop based on the Id of the Goal and the Main objectives

Comment: `if(ID matches the other ID) break;` or `break N;` where N is the nesting level

Comment: Can you provide an example in code format pls?